# error while doing return to SQL export in function

Tags: php

I'm getting error when I writing:

```
$res = mysql_query($query);
$index = mysql_fetch_array($res);

if ($table == "users_sch");
    return ($res);
else
    return ($index);
```

Parse error: parse error in C:\Progr...

error point on the ELSE line

why is that?

Comment: Post your entire error

Comment: This question was caused by a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($table == "users_sch"); // here remove `;`
```

**NOTE:** Due to readability and nice code I'd suggest you to use curly braces {}

Comment: While abuse who is downvoting without any reason, its better for him to show himself